# I am trying to get Attribute of input of type checbox but it keeps getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: a.getAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get Attribute of input of type checbox but it keeps getting this error:
        "Uncaught TypeError: a.getAttribute is not a function"

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    var fields = document.getElementsByClassName("checkBox");
    for(a in fields){
        var x = a.getAttribute("id");
        console.log(x);
}
```

please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're including jQuery, then use jQuery. Mixing it with plain JS is prone to headaches and errors.

Comment: You are using the [for...in statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) both incorrectly and in the wrong use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here `a` will be an integer, as `a` is the index specifically, because `for...in` iterates through object keys, and the indices are the array object keys<sup>[AndrewLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44549955/i-am-trying-to-get-attribute-of-input-of-type-checbox-but-it-keeps-getting-this/44549991?noredirect=1#comment76090586_44549991)</sup>:

```
for (a in fields){
    var x = fields[a].getAttribute("id");
```

Or the better way to do is:

```
for (var a = 0; a < fields.length; a++)
    var x = fields[a].getAttribute("id");
```

If you are using jQuery, as you have tagged it, please use:

```
$(".checkBox").each(function () {
  var x = this.id;
  console.log(x);
});
```

It is worth mentioning that it's important to prevent the default action:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
```

With all the above said, your final code should be:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
  $(".checkBox").each(function () {
    var x = this.id;
    console.log(x);
  });
});  // missing );
```

Please note the missing braces.

Comment: You might want to say why `a` will be an integer -- the index specifically, because for...in iterates through object keys, and the indices are the array object keys.

Comment: @AndrewLi Sure, will add it now.

Comment: @AndrewLi Added you a reference bro!

Comment: Thanks, used a simple for loop instead